# Prevent backslash from being parsed by javascript for a string

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, backslash

A Flash AS3 IRC application passes me a string like "f\reak" to JavaScript. IRC allows the \ in usernames which poses a problem when its passed to JavaScript.

**"f\reak"** become **"feak"** in javascript making the **\r** into a carriage return.

Is there a way to read the absolute value of the string instead of parsing a carriage return?

These methods didn't work
str.valueOf()
str.toString()
str.charAt(position of the \ )  this just sees the carriage return as well and not a backslash

Comment: Something sounds off. Are you sure your JavaScript is being passed an actual backslash, and it's not just the Flash app screwing up?

Comment: ActionScript is a based on ECMAScript (aka. JavaScript) and uses the same escape characters, so the problem probably appear allready in the flash app. Escapes is only relevant in string literals or 
when printing to a different system using other escape characters..

Comment: My point is the flash app is probably sending you a carriage return, wich is correctly handled as a carriage return by javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Though it doesn't seem a optimal way, I can recommend you one thing. So, first of all you need to know all the escape sequences in javascript. You can get those [here](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/special_characters.htm). Now as there are not too many of them, you can check the presence of each of the escape sequences individually in the provided string. To do this you can use

```
if(str.length!=str.replace("\r","")) //To check whether "\r" is present or not.
```

Similarly you have to do for other escape sequences. So, nevertheless of any string you will at least know whether any escape sequences are there are not and if yes you can handle that string as per your requirement.